# Randomly choose an array element in a non-full array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a program where I am creating an `arrayList`. One method randomly removes an item from the list. I also have a method that resizes the array if a certain amount of elements are added to make space for more elements to be added if wanted.

I am receiving a `NullPointerExceptionError` when the lists are resized and then the method tries to remove one of the `null` spaces in the newly resized array.

Without using a for loop and keeping a constant time, I'm trying to find a way to make my `int` value of `choice` just the number of non `null` elements in the array. I hope that makes sense - can anyone help?

`remove` method:

```
public T remove() {
  if (isEmpty()) {
     return null;
  }
  Random rand = new Random();
  int choice = rand.nextInt(size);
  size--;
  elements[choice] = elements[size];
  elements[size] = null;
  return elements[choice];
}
```

Comment: This is not returning the random element chosen so you will get duplicates.  This code might trigger an NPE if `isEmpty()` is true.

Comment: I see no array list here.  I see an *array*.  They don't automatically shrink because `null` elements are present.

Comment: it was meant to say array-based list, my apologies. This is correct, not supposed to be an array list.

Answer (score 2):

This question boils down to "Given an array with null elements scattered throughout, how can I return the nth non-null element?" The answer is iterate through the array, which doesn't uphold the constant time constraint your're looking for.

But wait, how can array lists work in that case?!? 
Here is how `java.util.ArrayList` does it:

```
@Override
public E get(int location) {
    if (0 <= location && location < (lastIndex - firstIndex)) {
        return (E) array[firstIndex + location];
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Messages.getString("luni.0A",
            location, lastIndex - firstIndex));
}
```

Note that there are no null checks, the Arraylist always maintains its elements in a contiguous block so gets are super fast. So some magic must happen when removing elements so there won't be nulls scattered about...

```
@Override
public E remove(int location) {
    E result;
    int localLastIndex = lastIndex;
    int size = localLastIndex - firstIndex;
    if (0 <= location && location < size) {
        if (location == size - 1) {
            result = (E) array[--localLastIndex];
            array[localLastIndex] = null;
        } else if (location == 0) {
            result = (E) array[firstIndex];
            array[firstIndex++] = null;
        } else {
            int elementIndex = firstIndex + location;
            result = (E) array[elementIndex];
            if (location < size / 2) {
                System.arraycopy(array, firstIndex, array, firstIndex + 1,
                        location);
                array[firstIndex++] = null;
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(array, elementIndex + 1, array,
                        elementIndex, size - location - 1);
                array[--localLastIndex] = null;
            }
        }
        if (firstIndex == localLastIndex) {
            firstIndex = localLastIndex = 0;
        }
    } else {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Messages.getString("luni.0A",
                location, localLastIndex - firstIndex));
    }
    lastIndex = localLastIndex;
    modCount++;
    return result;
}
```

There is the key! When removing an element the JDK impl doesn't leave a gap, nor does it move all the elements over to close the gap. It calls a native method that copies a chunk of array around as an atomic operation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)